# how to modify the text property for all object in the form at run windows form c#

Tags: c#, .net

I have a form like Invoice and more forms in my application and have a lot of controls in form like text box , label , datagrid , tree view and other

I want make a Method to read  the object by object from this form to change text property or caption property   - its will be useful to let the user change the control caption by himself when the program complete -

Note : some controls include object like Navbar control or datagrid control have a columns or a nodes and I want to change Column and node Caption by code

best Regards

Answer (score 1):

For example,
`Label.Text = "My text";`

for  datagrid you will need to access the cell of which text you wish to change.
I'd recommend you to go through all the methods and properties of all controls that appears in intellisense. It will guide and teach you alot.
such as write the control name and write Dot after it.

`DataGrid.` 
an Intellisense will appear with methods with their summary. Read them to find out what they do and use them.

`DataGrid.Rows[array as it is Enumerable].Cells[array as it is Enumerable].Value` <- This is a hint for you to find out yourself. It will be slow but it will make you independent. Good luck :)

You can achieve to change the text for the treenode at any level with the guide i provided above. Just go through the Intellisense and you'll start to understand what you need to do.

Comment: Thank you
you don't Understand me >>> I wand to make a method like the Following : 

foreach (var x in this.Controls)
            {                              MessageBox.Show(x.GetType().GetProperty("Name").GetValue(x).ToString());
                
                x.GetType().GetProperty("Text").SetValue(x,"New");
            }
But this Methd Not Include The Other Object Like DataGrid Columns Or NavBae Node

Comment: i did my friend. directly pass DataGrid and TreeView(Navbar) to check what properties intellisense populates. like `var x = DataGrid;`
now type  `X.` to get the list of methods and properties check.